# Loop unrolling with OMP

Tags: multithreading, opencv, c++11, openmp

I have applied loop enrolling as mentioned in [this post](http://fastcpp.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-unroll-loop-in-c.html)

Code:

```
for(i = 0; i< ROUND_DOWN(contours.size(),3);i+=3)
{
cv::convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);
cv::convexHull(contours[i+1], convexHulls[i+1]);
cv::convexHull(contours[i+2], convexHulls[i+2]);
}
```

Now I want to use multiple threads (3) in the for loop so each thread only execute one statement in the loop some what like section using openmp.

How to do so?

I tried this:

```
for(i = 0; i< ROUND_DOWN(contours.size(),3);i+=3)
{
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
#pragma omp section
cv::convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);
#pragma omp section
cv::convexHull(contours[i+1], convexHulls[i+1]);
#pragma omp section
cv::convexHull(contours[i+2], convexHulls[i+2]);
}
}
```

But it didn't work and I got an error can someone tell me how to do this right?

I did get [another post](http://fastcpp.blogspot.in/2011/12/template-based-vector-library-with-sse.html). In this SSE instructions are used but I am unable to make sense of it.

Comment: I think you should first explain why you think you need to unroll?  What does `cv::convexHull` do? The main reason to unroll is due to dependency chains which are latency bound. This applies to a single core. If you unroll in this case you don't have to do anything more because the unrolling breaks the chain and your out-of-order processor takes care of the rest.

Comment: Most importantly, what error do you get? You should consider the most important sentence in the referenced article: *Unrolling loops by yourself is often not necessary as a good C++ compiler will do that for you* If you do it without reason, it is premature optimization.

Comment: contours is an array and cv::convexhull is a function which takes a contour and apply convex hull to it. I have used loopenrolling for 2 reasons :- 1.) So that conditions are checked less times 2.) By using multiple threads I want to execute conexhull function in parallel to make program more optimal

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a parallel for:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);
}
```

This expresses what you want to do and allows the compiler and runtime to run the loop in parallel. For instance this will work with any thread configuration or size, while your suggestion will only work properly for three threads.

Don't help the compiler unless you have evidence or strong knowledge that it is beneficial. If you ever do, verify that it is actually beneficial. If the simple version does not perform good in your case, you should first give the compiler hints (e.g. scheduling strategies) rather than implementing your own manually.

Note that this will only work properly, if there are certain data dependencies between loop iterations (same with your section code). Your code looks like this is not the case, but a certain evaluation would require a proper complete code example.

Comment: There is a another case for unrolling besides dependency chains.  You can amortize the cost of the loop (increment/decrement iterator, test, and jump) by unrolling. This often has a smaller effect than breaking dependency chains but it's sometimes necessary to maximize throughput. OTOH it can lead to other problems because it uses more code. So it's not necessarily better. But in any case, these are micro optimizations which most people probably should not worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to parallelize using `sections`. It is not clear what kind of dependencies you have in the `cv::convexHull` function but if there are no side-effects (as I think) you should be able to parallelize simply using work-sharing:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(e)
for(i = 0; i< ROUND_DOWN(contours.size(),3); i+=3)
{
  cv::convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);
  cv::convexHull(contours[i+1], convexHulls[i+1]);
  cv::convexHull(contours[i+2], convexHulls[i+2]);
}
```